# Matrices that commute with Elements from the Symmetric-Group and the Hyperoctahedral Group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, permutation-matrices

I am wondering whether people would have references for simple examples about:

- Matrices that commute with elements of the Symmetric-Group, e.g. matrix $A$ as below, and the Hyperoctahedral Group, i.e. matrix $B$ as below.
- Efficient decomposition and projection into the "symmetric space"
  $$
  A = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
       1&2&3&7&8&9\\
       4&5&6&10&11&12\\
      12&11&10&6&5&4\\
       9&8&7&3&2&1
  \end{bmatrix}\quad
  B = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
       1&2&3&7&8&9\\
       4&5&6&10&11&12\\
      -12&-11&-10&-6&-5&-4\\
       -9&-8&-7&-3&-2&-1
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$

I have already worked with matrices that are invariant to cyclic permutations (circulant matrices), for which the efficient transformation is described by the discrete Fourier transformation.

It would be very helpful if you could point me at some books/papers/posts with as many examples as possible. I am currently trying to avoid books like *Linear Representations of Finite Groups* by J.P Serre.

Thank you very much in advance.

EDIT:
By invariance I mean that if one forms a permutation matrix $P_n\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ with ones on the anti-diagonal, i.e.
$$
P_4 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and if one pre- and post-multiplies $A$ or $B$ by $P_4$ and $P_6$, respectively, it holds that:
$$P_4 A = AP_6, \qquad P_4 B = -BP_6.$$

As far as I know, such matrices come with transformation matrices $T$ that "sparsify" the original matrix and map a vector $x$ into the "symmetric space". Moreover, in most cases the product $T x$ can be computed very efficiently (that is my interest in this).

I probably use lots of clumsy formulations above and would also be happy if you could correct the terms I am using which would make my search for literature easier.

Comment: In what sense is $A$ invariant under the action of $S_n$?

Comment: Thank you for your respons @MattSamuel I edited the question. I hope that it is clearer now.

Comment: What do your two properties have to do with $S_n$ and $H_n$? Words like "invariant to the action of [blah]" already mean things in math, and they do not mean what you are talking about.

Comment: Isn't $\Omega_4$ a group action (permutation) from the symmetric-group $S_n$?

Comment: No. It's a single permutation matrix, not a group action.

Comment: I thought that the symmetric-group $S_2$ has exactly two elements: the identity element and a permutation swapping two points. That would correspond to the identity matrix and the permutation matrix. Please correct me if I am wrong?
I might be confusing terms. Maybe the group action for these groups is function composition? And the elements of the group are these permutation matrices?

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant actions of $S_4$ and $S_6$ since you were talking about $4\times4$ and $6\times 6$ permutation matrices and used  a generic letter $n$ in the notation $S_n$, but you simply meant a nonstandard $S_2$ action (in which case you might as well just say $\mathbb{Z}_2$)? In that case it is invariant.

Comment: I made an attempt at improving the question. I hope that it's clearer now.

Comment: Clearer, but still not clear. What do you mean by "diagonalization" for non-square matrices? If by "mapping into the symmtric space" you mean projection: For your $A$ example, the space is the space of matrices where pairs of entries related by inversion are equal; so the projection onto the space is the map that replaces the elements of each such pair by its average.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I agree that diagonalization was the wrong word. Changed it to decomposition.  I also changed mapping to projection. I am currently not able to add more details. But yes, I mean some projection/change of coordinates which decomposes $A$. I found some information on [wikipedia](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_groups) under character tables, $n=2$, however, without references and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Without correcting the various sloppy statements I made before (e.g. irreducible  basis should be irreducible representations), the solution was rather obvious. Given $\tilde{A}$ from my previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3661472), for which I know the decomposition, one first needs to bring $A$ into a similar form to $\tilde{A}$. This can be done by pre- and post-multiplying $A$ by the invertible $S_l$ and $S_r$, respectively, where
$$
S_l=I_2\oplus P_2,\qquad\qquad
S_r=I_3\oplus P_3,
$$
and where $\oplus$ denotes the block-diagonal concatenation. Then $S_l A S_r$ has the same form than $\tilde{A}$ and is decomposed as in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3661472).

Finally, the terms to look for in the literature, are:
Linear Representation Theory, Irreducible Representations and Character Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Following doesn't answer my question, but I think that it might be related. Following matrix $\tilde{A}$,
$$
\tilde{A} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
     1&2&3&7&8&9\\
     4&5&6&10&11&12\\
     7&8&9&1&2&3\\
     10&11&12&4&5&6
\end{bmatrix},
$$
commutes with $P_2\otimes I_2$, where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product. Two block-wise flips around the centered vertical and horizontal axis yield the same matrix again. A matrix with this property is decomposed into two blocks of size $2\times 3$ by $(T\otimes I_2)^T\tilde{A}(T\otimes I_3)$, where
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\ -1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
represents a projection onto - please correct me if I am wrong - the *irreducible basis* of the symmetric-group $S_2$, which is also referred to as the cyclic group or denoted as $\mathbb{Z}_2$. As mentioned in Joriki's comment to my initial [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3659947), this represents an average and a difference of two directions. An academic example of a dynamical system with this property is a string of e.g. 4 identical mass-spring-damper systems, for which the 1st "symmetric movement" is a movement where all masses move in one direction and the 2nd  "symmetric movement" is one where the 2 left-hand masses move in one and the two right-hand masses move in the other direction.

The difference between $A$ and $\tilde{A}$ is that one needs to flip all elements of $A$ around the centered vertical and horizontal axis to obtain $A$ again, rather than a block-wise flip.

Does somebody here think that there is also such an irreducible basis for $A$?